# Opening a drop down and then changing the default value

Tags: asp.net

If I have a drop down box, how can I have a default selection (know how to do this) which will change to another member in the drop down upon opening of the drop down?

For example: My drop down has 2 values - "Hello", and "Hello Back". "Hello" is the default (0) value, but how can I display "Hello Back" when the drop down box is opened?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand the question.  What do you mean by when it's opened?  When the user clicks on the dropdown you want to change the selected item?

Comment: And are you looking for javascript or code-behind?

Comment: I would assume this needs to be client side script from the description as he wants the selected item to change when opening the drop down list in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use javascript to implement something like this. A basic example based on what you have requested is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectOption()
{
    var thisDLL = document.getElementById("myDDL").options[1].selected = "true";
}
<select id="myDDL" name="myDDL" onclick="javascript:selectOption();">
   <option value="Hello" selected="true" >Hello</option>
   <option value="Hello back" selected="true">Hello back</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively you could fire the event on using the onFocus event.

EDIT: Fixed error in javascript

Answer (score 0):

u can use Dropdownlist's findbyvalue  or findbytext method by giving Hello Back's value or Text as parameter.forexample you can do it so.

dropdownlist1.items.findbytext("Hello Back").selected=true